# Setting NSTextView selection font name

Tags: objective-c, macos

I can change the selected text font name in a text view as:

```
NSMutableDictionary *attributes = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[attributes setObject: [NSFont fontWithName:"Tahoma" size:20] forKey:
    NSFontAttributeName];
[[textView textStorage] setAttributes:attributes range:[textView selectedRange]];
```

Above code works only if I have selection range. If my text view has no selection the code has no effect and typing font does not change.
I want to change the font at cursor (if text view has no selection) and not whole of text view. (like text edit)
any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the attributes that will be applied to newly entered text with `-[NSTextView  setTypingAttributes:]`.